# Updating GUI components in class B from class A in c#

Tags: c#, .net, class

EDIT: I see I'm getting a lot of downvotes on this post. I've tried to explain what I try to do, where my errors and in which direction want to go. I'm asking for insight in what I'm doing wrong. If you downvote; pleas tell me why, so I can improve the question. Thanks.

I'm creating an application where I have one main form, and several different User Controls which the user works on. This helps me splitting the code, managing the different parts of the program. And it would be easy to expand the application later on.

I'm trying to create a class where I manage the active controls I want to call one function in that class with as argument the form that should become active.

An image can illustrate how I try to setup this application. [image: Illustration] Note that the control manager class is not a seperate class in the code i show below, but a partial class of the mainform. Any tips on how to get it like in the image are very welcome :)

The class to manage all active forms looks like this: Please note that all user controls are just a user control with some buttons/textboxes etc on it. No code is added at all yet.

```
    public partial class STP2Main 
        {
// I make each UserControl accessable for the whole class
            SetupDeviceControl.SetupDevice SetupDev = new SetupDeviceControl.SetupDevice();
            GenConfigFileControl.GenConfigFileControl GenConfFile = new GenConfigFileControl.GenConfigFileControl();
            Monitoring.MonitoringControl Monitor = new Monitoring.MonitoringControl();
            GenEncKeyControl.GenEncKeyControl GenEncKey = new GenEncKeyControl.GenEncKeyControl();
            MenuControl.MenuControl MenuControl = new MenuControl.MenuControl();        

            public void SelectActiveWindow()
            {
                // Any active control should be hidden thats what this function does:
                HideCurrentActiveControl();
                // Check whether the window is already created
                if (!WindowExists())
                { // if not created; create the windows: 
                    switch (STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.NextActiveControl)
                    {
                        case STP_Data.Data.SetupDeviceControl: // control 1:
                            STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.CurrentActiveControl = STP_Data.Data.SetupDeviceControl;
                            STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.SetupDeviceControlIsCreated = true;
                            SetupDev.Parent = this;
                            SetupDev.Location = new Point(3, 30);
                            SetupDev.Show();
                            SetupDev.BringToFront();
                            break;
                        case STP_Data.Data.MonitoringControl: //control 2:
                            STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.CurrentActiveControl = STP_Data.Data.MonitoringControl;
                            STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.MonitoringControlIsCreated = true;
                            Monitor.Parent = this;
                            Monitor.Location = new Point(3, 125);
                            Monitor.Show();
                            Monitor.BringToFront();
                            break;
                        case STP_Data.Data.MenuControl: // control 3
                            STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.CurrentActiveControl = STP_Data.Data.MenuControl;
                            STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.MenuControlIsCreated = true;  
                            MenuControl.Location = new Point(3, 30);
                            MenuControl.Parent = this;
                            MenuControl.Show();
                            MenuControl.BringToFront();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                { // window is already created so needs to be called to front again:
                    switch (STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.NextActiveControl)
                    {
                        case STP_Data.Data.SetupDeviceControl:
                            STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.CurrentActiveControl = STP_Data.Data.SetupDeviceControl;
                            SetupDev.BringToFront();
                            break;
                        case STP_Data.Data.MonitoringControl:
                            STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.CurrentActiveControl = STP_Data.Data.MonitoringControl;
                            Monitor.Visible = true;
                            Monitor.BringToFront();
                            break;
                        case STP_Data.Data.AdvancedMenu:
                            STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.CurrentActiveControl = STP_Data.Data.AdvancedMenu;
                            tabControl1.Visible = true;
                            tabControl1.BringToFront();
                            break;

                        case STP_Data.Data.MenuControl:
                            STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.CurrentActiveControl = STP_Data.Data.MenuControl;
                            MenuControl.Visible = true;
                            MenuControl.BringToFront();
                            break;
                    }

                }
                btnMenu.BringToFront();

            }
    // some functions which are called above are not shown; not relevant for this question
    }
```

What I experience is the following: I get no errors at all. But the controls simply not change at all. If I call a window, it is created only once, because I did make it as partial class of my Mainform. (I've tried a complete seperate class, which did result in errors with threading, As I am not an experienced c# programmer, I tried to avoid that using a partial class.)

I'll add another function; which does not do anything at all:

```
    private void HideCurrentActiveControl()
    {
        switch (STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.CurrentActiveControl)
        {
            case STP_Data.Data.SetupDeviceControl:
                SetupDev.Visible = false;
                break;
            case STP_Data.Data.MonitoringControl:
                tabControl1.Visible = false;
                Monitor.Visible = false;
                break;
            case STP_Data.Data.GenConfFileControl:
                GenConfFile.Visible = false;
                break;
            case STP_Data.Data.GenEncKeyControl:
                GenEncKey.Visible = false;
                break;
            case STP_Data.Data.MenuControl:
                MenuControl.Visible = false;
                break;
            case STP_Data.Data.AdvancedMenu:
                tabControl1.Visible = false;
                break;
            default:
                tabControl1.Visible = false;
                break;

        }
    }
```

I've tried debugging this part of code and it executes the statements, but I see no changes at all.

I think I've shown what I am trying to do; and how I try to do that. My question is: How do I acces those forms so I can manage them from a seperate class (or in this case partial class of the main form).

Then I have this last function, which does some wierd things. Before I call the SelectActiveWindow() function I update the variable STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.NextActiveControl to for example:  ...AdvancedMenu. (this was before that ...MenuControl) But it does always show that it is still MenuControl. Nowhere in my code is something where I change that value besides right before I start the function. (I've also tried to make the nextcontrol as an argument of the function SelectActiveWindow() but this did the same)

```
    private bool WindowExists()
    {
        switch (STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.NextActiveControl)
        {
            case STP_Data.Data.SetupDeviceControl:
                if (STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.SetupDeviceControlIsCreated)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            case STP_Data.Data.MonitoringControl:
                if (STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.MonitoringControlIsCreated)
                    return true;
                else
                return false;
            case STP_Data.Data.GenConfFileControl:
                if (STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.GenConfFileIsCreated)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            case STP_Data.Data.GenEncKeyControl:
                if (STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.GenEncKeyControlIsCreated)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            case STP_Data.Data.AdvancedMenu:
                return true;
            case STP_Data.Data.MenuControl:
                if (STP_Design.ProgramParameters.C.MenuControlIsCreated)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Summery of what I am looking for: 
I am having a main form where display different user controlls in. I am trying to create a seperate class which is accessable from each control/form in my project. This class should manage the controls which are shown. In the code above I illustrated how I tried to do this, but this does not result in the expected result.

Comment: Control identifiers are *private* by default.  You can change the Modifiers property in the Properties window.  Or just add a public method to class a.

Comment: Refresh(); it is a handy thing to make the page redraw after you change something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Now I understand the context needed.  We actually do something very similar in my program.  Here is a basic outline of how we do it...

**Layout**

On the main form we have a *Panel* container that we call `pnlMain`.  It is this control that we add and remove active user controls from.  We also have a *UserControl* object at a global level on the form representing `curActiveControl`.

**Code**

When the user selects a window via one of the menu's, we run a function that looks like this

```
switch (UserSelection)
{
    case "Page 1":
        if(curActiveControl.GetType() != typeOf(Page1Control))
        {
            pnlMain.Controls.Remove(curActiveControl);
            curActiveControl = new Page1Control();
            //do setup and configuration things
            pnlMain.Controls.Add(curActiveControl);
        }
        //do some post processing things
        break;
    //other pages/specific page controls
}

Refresh();
```

The downside to this specific method is that the pages themselves are not persistent, so if there are entries or variables you want to have active across a session rather than only while on a page, you have to store them in some other global object and reload them from the user control's Load or Constructor methods.

You could do this same thing but instead of creating a new control instance each time for `curActiveControl` you could simply replace it with the standby instance of the new control.  Be careful with referencing and overwriting though, its not something I personally have tried before.

The key in the method we use is the Panel that holds the user controls.  Rather than adjusting the visibility and Z-Order of a large number of user controls, we simply change the displayed control in the main panel and the other control don't even exist at any given point in time.

The other wrinkle is that this functionality is directly on our Main Form.  I Don't know how well this will work as another partial class.  Its definitely worth a try though.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. This wont work because of the `new` keyword. If i create a new class, i wont get acces to the controls on the existing form (what I want) but i get acces to the controls of the new form.

Comment: so you need method 2 then, you have to pass the specific reference you need into the class somehow.  You can either do this when the class is created via the constructor, afterwards via a public pointer of some kind, or at the method level using the method parameters...but you have to specifically provide the reference you need otherwise the code can't see it.

Comment: I've updated my question as I felt that it is not constructive for the comunity. I've expanded it, but i think there is more information in it for further use.

Comment: I changed my entire answer based on the change to the question. Have a look =D

Comment: Thank you for this explaination! As you say the pages themselves are not persistant, can be changed by changing visibility. Thats what I did. I've also found where the error was (FINALLY after 2 days stuggeling). I was missing an "=" I tried `var temp this.Parent as STP2Main` and call the function like this `temp.SelectActiveWindow()` but I kept getting errors on `var temp... ` adding a "=" between `temp` and `this.Parent` solved this problem. I'm very interested in putting this function in a seperate class in stead of the mainform. Do you know good resources  where I can read more about that?