# Application performance when using user controls C#

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

I'm working on somewhat large application that is divided into groups by functionality. Since every functionality is mostly independent (they all use the same database, but there is no direct interaction between different functionalities), I'm using the user defined controls and treating them as individual "applications". The way the application works is this:

- The "root" application only contains the main menu and 2 panels. The main menu is used to select the group of functionalities.
- After the group is selected (on application startup the first group is automatically selected), the functionalities (represented by buttons) from that group are displayed in the first panel.
- The user selects the functionality (by clicking on the appropriate button) he/she wants and the user control that contains the "form" is displayed in the second panel.
  The code that displays all of the user controls looks like this:

  ```
      panel2.Controls.Clear();
      UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
      uc1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
      panel2.Controls.Add(uc1);
      label6.Text = "User control 1";
  ```

So, when the user selects one of the functionalities, the application clears existing controls, and displays the selected one.
The application works fine (the part I implemented so far), so this is my question - how does this approach manage computer resources, mainly the memory. Specifically, if the user uses one functionality, and then switches to another one, will the .NET's services release the memory used by the previous functionality (I think garbage collector is in charge of that) and will the SQL connections, that I use to communicate with the database, be closed?
Also, are there some other issues that I should be aware of?
As I said, the functionalities work properly, but I'm still very far from full testing of the application as a whole (I only test every functionality individually when I create it, and only on the computer I create it on, so I can't consider it as a proper testing). Because of that, I am worried that the application's performances might deteriorate if the application is constantly used over a longer period of time.
I'm using VS 2010 (C#) and SQL Server 2005 to create this application.
If you have any suggestions, please write them. With this question, I'm trying to prevent major reconstructions of the application once it comes to the phase of testing and implementing due to bad resource management.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbage collector is in charge of freeing up the memory that belongs to objects that are **not referenced anywhere**. If your Windows Forms' Form shows many controls at once, they **are all somehow referenced** by the form at the time, so the GC won't clean anything up here, you need to be careful not to load too many objects in these controls. Furthermore, you may run into memory issues if you do not properly `Dispose` the controls before calling the `panel2.Controls.Clean()`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking - I thought `panel2.Controls.Clear()` was removing the control (not just from the display, but also from the memory). The application is designed so it will only display one user control at time. So will the Dispose() method release the memory used by the previous controls? Also, is there a way to show which controls are referenced at a particular moment during run time?

Comment: Yes, if you call Dispose on the controls that have been previously used, and if these controls are properly implemented (e.g. they dispose their own components in turn), the memory shall be freed up. However, the approach seems to add unnecessary overhead of memory management to your application. Did you consider using different Forms for different features? Closing and disposing a Form is certainly easier than to manage a panel.

Comment: As for `show which controls are referenced at a particular moment during run time`, you probably need to use a memory profiling tool. Search in the Web `JetBrains dotTrace` and `ANTS Memory profiler` - they are pretty useful in measuring what eats the memory and how to fix any leaks.

Comment: Yes, using multiple forms was my first idea, but my client said that that approach is to "messy". This application will be used by users with only basic knowledge of computer usage, so I have to make it as user friendly as possible. Using multiple forms might be confusing to such users.

Comment: `panel2.Controls.Clear()` will actually clean references to controls from the Panel, but it won't call `Dispose` on controls. If there are no references to an object, GC will try to destroy it, and Control's destructor, if properly implemented, will call `Dispose` anyways. But it nevertheless is advisable to `Dispose` things beforehand (i.e. as soon as you don't need this instance).

Comment: `I have to make it as user friendly as possible` >> consider also using multiple tabs UI or something like that, there are plenty of solutions already implemented. Managing a Panel will require you to maintain a quite complex controls solution. Are you sure you are not inventing a bicycle?

Comment: The problem is that I'm creating this application based on an existing application that my client already has. Because of that, I have to make the user interface similar to the existing one so that the "transition" period is as short as possible. And yes, I am certain that I'm `inventing a bicycle`, but unfortunately that is the situation I'm in.

Comment: Oh, I see, the legacy code is big problem for anyone facing it. It just seems that the trick you are trying to accomplish nicely fits to the paradigm of the TabControl in Windows Forms, with an only exception that you don't need the tabs to be visible. Also, you may try to implement your features as different UserControls, probably deriving from a base class for easier management. Otherwise, the code where you manage the `panel2` may get quite complex and hard to maintain as you get deeper into development.

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating an application like this too. What I experience is a lot of difficultys when it comes to managing the controls (See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123061/updating-gui-components-in-class-b-from-class-a-in-c-sharp/) here on stackoverflow)

My expectations are that the memory used by the application can become a lot. You should close controls you do not need anymore to prevent this. Also the connections with SQL, I'd reccomend to open/close them manually, so you can be sure there are no conflicts later.